# How do I transfer my Skyrim game to another computer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So my computer's gettin' old and my folks are planning to get me another laptop for college. Since I'll never forget my current laptop and its content, how am I gonna transfer the files (specifically Skyrim, since mine is heavily modded, I'd love a solution wherein my mods can also be transferred) to another laptop? Lastly, what will I also need, like things to buy?

Comment: You CAN try just sticking the old drive into the new laptop and see how the OS handles that.  Windows 7 and on seems to be able to handle that better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to download Skyrim through Steam to your new computer. Make sure to copy your `Documents\My Games\Skyrim` folder to your new computer.

Because you're using a modded environment, you need to move your mods over as well. This really depends on what tool you're using though:

### Mod Organizer

---

> **Author's Note**: If you're not already using Mod Organizer, I recommend you drop everything and go start using it now. It makes managing Skyrim mods infinitely easier, and it's fully compatible with NexusMods.

If you're using Mod Organizer, your job is (thankfully) very simple.

1. Download and install Mod Organizer on your new computer.
2. On your old PC, navigate to where you installed MO (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)` (or `C:\Program Files` if you have a 32-bit PC)) and copy that folder to a new pen drive.
3. Replace the `Mod Organizer` folder on your new PC (where you installed MO on your new PC) with the one you just extracted from your old PC.

All of your mods and saves should be present. Note that you might need to re-install SKSE or any other base mods that you have in your system.

### Nexus Mod Manager

---

Unfortunately, NMM doesn't really have a set/official method that I was able to find. However, it should still be *relatively* simple.

1. Install NMM on your new PC.
2. On your old PC, all of your mods should be in the folder `C:\Games\Nexus Mod Manager\Skyrim`. Copy this to your new PC.

### Steam Mods

---

<s>Okay, you're a casual.</s> Steam Workshop mods should move right over, no problem.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain their downvote so I can fix the problem in the post and/or make better posts in the future? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the folder where game is stored and paste it on the other computer (in the exact same location)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using steam, then all you have to do is download from the cloud on the other/next PC once steam is on it

Comment: Sadly, no. But thank you for the response!

Comment: @SEBASSZCHAN it was worth a shot at least!

Comment: Non-steam mods won't transfer over.

Comment: This is why we have steam